# Using Geolocation to load a map in a bootstrap modal, the marker is not centered

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to center a marker in a map loaded in a bootstrap modal based on geolocation for getting the current location of the user. The rest has been explained in this fiddle ...
[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hilbi/n3Lgt63p/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#locate" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</a>
<div id="locate" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">                               
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title-contact">My Location</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">              
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>                          
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function initMap(){

  var loc = {lat:0,lng:0};
  if (navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }
  else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }

function showPosition(position){ 
  loc.lat=position.coords.latitude;
  loc.lng=position.coords.longitude;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);
  console.log(latLng);
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var markerOptions = new google.maps.Marker({
    clickable: true,
    flat: true,
    map: map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    title: "You are here",
    visible:true,
    icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
      }
    });
  } 
  }

  var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: latLong,
    useCurrentLocation : true,
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(latLong);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
    if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16); 
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
    });

$('#locate').on('shown', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

});
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the center of the map before you trigger the resize-event and re-assign the center after triggering the resize-event:

```
$('#locate').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   var center=map.getCenter();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center);
});
```

[**https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9tr8dmax/**](https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9tr8dmax/)

Comment: You solved the map loading issue too on your way to give a solution. Thanks :-)